# Interpreting Java objects on browser side and JavaScript objects on server side

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, marshalling, javascript-framework

I am asking an age old question. 
What is the best framework/technology to unmarshall/marshall javascript objects to Java objects and vice versa?

I know that passing the XML around is a starting point but now this option has been exhausted for our application. I am hearing a lot about JSON these days but not sure how good it is in keeping the object model intact. I don't want fall into XML trap again.

Other than JSON, I am analyzing DWR framework too.

Is there any other framework/technology which provides solution to this problem?

Comment: I looked at DWR which will do what you are describing, though it is more RPC, than direct object marshalling/unmarshalling. Just be aware that security wise there are some large holes that could be exploited depending on what you are doing. If you are inserting server-side logic into the javascript you are giving access to said logic to anyone who uses the web page.

Comment: json is fine and much much lighter than XML. Use a library like gson and you'll see your code may remain very simple. But you should have a different model on each side and just exchange data objects.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Then what do you suggest?

Comment: @dystroy Did you mean that client side and server side will have different object models and I should use some marshalling/unmarshalling in between?

Comment: I like to have very light objects acting as a common model, in order to keep javascript & com simple and prevent the complexity (and changes) of the server model to impact the browser side.

Comment: It is difficult to provide a recommendation when there is very little information about what you are trying to do. Are you serializing client input, some data from another program? DWR is not a bad thing, it just depends on what you are using it for. You should not be taking user input from the page, doing some client-side processing, then sending it back to the server with all this logic in your javascript. Instead, consider using php,  or jquery to ajax information back and forth, and do all the processing (and validation) on the server-side.

Comment: @thatidiotguy I am looking for a better integration between javascript and java than through xml. I understand that there should not be any business logic at the client side but I want keep my data model and its hierarchies in javascript same as java.

Comment: Then personally, I would recommend JSON as it is more lightweight than XML, and both Java and Javascript have great libraries to work with it. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Yadav I won't require a closing of this question but it's not the kind of question normally accepted : it is too wide and cannot be answered simply (that's the reason why thatidiotguy and me only commented). Please read the FAQ. Nevertheless, I'm happy if you're on you way for your application architecture :)